# Oracle user defined records

Tags: oracle, plsql

In Oracle PL/SQL records we can use anchor datatypes (including `%TYPE` and `%ROWTYPE`) to define the fields.

When I populate a record from a query, in my select clause I want type conversion. Is that possible using an Oracle built-in function or some other approach?

In this example scenario I am using a simple decode function to perform a conversion:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE TEST_RECORD IS RECORD(
    FIRST_NAME      EMPLOYEE_MT.FIRST_NAME%TYPE,
    LAST_NAME       EMPLOYEE_MT.LAST_NAME%TYPE,
    MARITIAL_STATUS EMPLOYEE_MT.MARITAL_STATUS%TYPE);
  EMPLOYEE_NAME TEST_RECORD;
BEGIN

  SELECT EMP.FIRST_NAME,
         EMP.LAST_NAME,
         DECODE(EMP.MARITAL_STATUS, 1, 'MARRIED', 0, 'UN-MARRIED')
    INTO EMPLOYEE_NAME
    FROM EMPLOYEE_MT EMP
   WHERE EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID = 1;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(EMPLOYEE_NAME.MARITIAL_STATUS);

END;
```

which gets error:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 9
```

Comment: [Please post your code and error as text not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Also include the table definition in your question so we can see the data types, and also perhaps some sample data.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your record type with the `maritial_status` (shouldn't that be `marital_status`?) field using the same data type as the table column. From your `decode` that appears to be a number data type. You're then trying to set the record's field value to a string, either 'MARRIED' or 'UN-MARRIED', when that field is expecting a number. Clearly neither of those strings can be converted to a number, hence the error you're getting.

If you want the record to store the string value, you'll have to define it like that - explicitly as a string, rather than using `%TYPE`:

```
DECLARE
  TYPE TEST_RECORD IS RECORD(
    FIRST_NAME     EMPLOYEE_MT.FIRST_NAME%TYPE,
    LAST_NAME      EMPLOYEE_MT.LAST_NAME%TYPE,
    MARITAL_STATUS VARCHAR2(10));
...
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(EMPLOYEE_NAME.MARITAL_STATUS);
...
```

You can't do that automatically using `%TYPE` as the data type just doesn't match. You've explicitly told Oracle that you want the field's data type to be a number, so Oracle isn't going to let you put a string in that field instead. It isn't about there not being a built-in function, it just doesn't make sense.

This also means you can't use `%ROWTYPE` if you're changing the data type either (unless your modified value can be implicitly converted back to the column data type).